# What does a string mean in a for loop assigned to a new variable? (Python 3)

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, range, tic-tac-toe

The beginner Python course I'm doing suggests drawing a board like this.

```
board = [" " for i in range(9)]

def print_board():

row1 = "|{}|{}|{}|".format(board[0], board[1], board[2])
row2 = "|{}|{}|{}|".format(board[3], board[4], board[5])
row3 = "|{}|{}|{}|".format(board[6], board[7], board[8])

print()
print(row1)
print(row2)
print(row3)
print()
```

What does the " " in

```
board = [" " for i in range(9)]
```

mean?

Comment: I bet the course also suggests indenting your scripts properly. Please do this. And why don't you print out `board` after it has been created to see, what it does? Change " " to "X" and 9 to 4 and it will be obvious to you.

Comment: This is a list comprehension. The `" "` creates a new string (of a single space character) every time round the for loop. This means that `board` ends up as a list of 9 space strings.

Comment: was gonna make answer but i've never seen this myself before. it makes an array with `"  "` using the for loop as its basis. So `for i in range(9)`, make one element with `"  "` for each iteration

Comment: i do agree with T though, EXPERIMENT! Put your own head into this instead of blindly following the tutorial. Change the number to 4 or change the string to "O" and see what it does.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I knew what happened when the code was executed but I didn't know why/what the code means in plain English

Comment: Thanks for the help @quamrana That's exactly what I wanted to know

Answer (score 2):

just do `print(board)`, it is a list of 9 "emtpy strings": `board = [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ']`